# Bring shipping methods not showing as guest customer

Tags: magento

I have a problem with this site: www.stramline.no

(It is in Norwegian).

As a customer with an account, the shipping method appear just fine.
However, as a guest, the shipping methods will not appear except "pick up in store". This is of course a big problem for many who are trying to purchase something.

Do you have any idea how to fix this? We have tried multiple checkout extensions, so we are sure that is not the problem. It also seems that I can log in, then log out, and the shipping methods will appear.

We are also using the X-POS extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem is that you haven't allowed the guest checkout from your magento backend.
To do this, go to system> configuration> checkout
and set "Allow Guest Checkout" to "Yes"
Clear cache after you've done this and it will work fine.
Note: I never use additional plugin/extension for shipping modules, I always create my own to avoid any future issues.